# How get IDEA Gradle task "run configuration" from editor working if using the `tasks.register()` syntax?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

IDEA has an inspection to automatically transform `task XXX()` to `tasks.register()`.

[image]

But if this syntax is used, you can no longer run commands from the `.gradle` source file: there's no gutter icon and nor will the "Run/Run context configuration" keyboard shortcut work.
Note that I can still run tasks from the Gradle tool view - just not from the editor.

[image]

[image]

Is there any config item or plugin or something I need to tweak to make this work again?

Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)

Comment: Please consider reviewing and accepting answers to your questions before opening new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an existing YouTrack Issue for this:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-315327/Gradle-Task-Gutter-Icons-do-not-exist-for-registered-tasks-ie-tasks.registertaskName

which you can upvote and comment on to raise its' priority for the developers.